# How to pull secrets from Kubernetes into GitHub action to run Django migrations for AKS deployment?

Tags: django, azure, kubernetes

I have taken up the challenge of automating the deployment of my company's Django-based application that is done with AKS but I am very new to it. My initial idea is to accomplish it by upgrading the steps in a GitHub workflow that acts on the release of a new version.

I have structured it with three jobs. `build`, `migrate` and `deploy`:

1. `build`: Simply build the Docker image and push it to the container registry on DockerHub - this step is successfully done.
2. `migrate`: Run the migrations in the production database from `python manage.py migrate` - here lies the problem.
3. `deploy`: Deploy the image to the Kubernetes cluster - successfully done.

Step 2 is the problem because we store the Postgres database credentials inside the Kubernetes cluster and to run the migrations I need those secrets to pass them as environment variables before I call the `migrate` command. So I am stuck on how I can pull those secrets from Kubernetes and use them to run a command in a step in GitHub action like this:

```yaml
migrate:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: psycopg2 prerequisites
        run: sudo apt-get install python3-dev libpq-dev

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      
      - name: Run migrations
        run: |
          POSTGRES_HOST={{ secret_host }} POSTGRES_USER={{ secret_user }} POSTGRES_PASSWORD={{ secret_password }} python manage.py showmigrations --settings settings_production
          POSTGRES_HOST={{ secret_host }} POSTGRES_USER={{ secret_user }} POSTGRES_PASSWORD={{ secret_password }} python manage.py migrate --settings settings_production
```

Question is, is this even possible? If so, how can I do it? If not, what is another option to run the migrations in production before finishing the deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rub db migrations from Kubernetes cluster itself.

1. Create a Kubernetes Job, which basically runs db migration. and
2. Deploy an init container before main container(application), which periodically checks db migration job completion.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could I just create a job in the github workflow that runs the init container with the migration before I run the job that deploys it?

Comment: Yes you can, but need to take care of concurrency issue when you have multiple replicas.

Comment: I just don't understand how the init container will run the latest migrations if the deployment with the new image (and codebase) is not yet in place. I don't know if I have a wrong understanding of it or what.

Comment: DB Migrations has nothing to do with deployments. However deployments need DB migrations(correct one) to work properly. Most of the time this approach works fine. However in some cases like architectural changes, you might need to make your hands dirty; here your manual intervention might be required.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the image I build and deploy contains the codebase with the new migration files already in them as we typically do `makemigrations` and push them to the repo so it's built in the image so what's left is the `migrate` command. If I use the same image in the init container will it work to define a specific command to run the migration even though the image already has a `CMD` to run containers?

Comment: Yes it should work with the same image, make sure to change the CMD according the need

Comment: Kubernetes helps you to override CMD present in the image, Please use it according to your need. Here you can call your db migration command.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: I haven't actually implemented because I am still researching about it but I will accept your answer because I see it's the way to go. Thank you for that!